# How to scroll to an IndexPath after apply the snapshot

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

Im facing issue that is related to scroll to IndexPath after collection view snapshot applied.
For this I have write bellow code

```
dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false, completion: {
    self.scrollToIndex(self.visibleIndex)
})
```

Unfortunately it is not working for me in < iOS 15

***Note: Working for iOS 15 and greater versions***

Answer (score 1):

Try performing the scroll operation after a short delay:

```
    dataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: false, completion: {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + .milliseconds(10)) {[weak self] in
            if let self  = self, let indexToScrollTo = self.visibleIndex {
                self.scrollToIndex(indexToScrollTo)
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: Thank you Karthik & Arik Segal

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this

```
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at:IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .right, animated: false)
```